# Getting Error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

When i run my website it gives me an error :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Here are some lines of code:

```
$grab=ngegrab('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='.$key.'&part=snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=10&q='.$qu.'&pageToken='.$yesPage.'&type=video'); 
$json = json_decode($grab);
$nextpage=$json->nextPageToken;
$prevpage=$json->prevPageToken;
if($json)
{
foreach ($json->items as $sam)
}
```

Comment: error is self explanatory -what would you like us to do about it ?

Comment: hahahhahahahah - i wish i had that magic power!

Comment: Cabernet Sauvignon darling

Answer (score 0):

before you use foreach, please check the $json->items is not empty, and you should use json_decode($grab, true);

Comment: `var_dump($json);` whats the result ?

Comment: do var_dump($json->items) to see what it is.

Comment: first check $grab , then check $json, and is $json->items a array?

Comment: LOL :v This is what i got after doing var_dump($grab); :
string(437) "{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "youtube.quota", "reason": "quotaExceeded", "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e." } } "

Comment: and after doing var_dump($json->items) 
i got NULL

Comment: Please check your request url, it return a error message, there is no 'items' in $grab...

Comment: it's not youtube error, the message said you were exceeded your quota. check the your max request times in googleapis.

Comment: It is, google owns youtube, look at the api the op is using